# ¿Que significa el uso del (+) en una consulta Oracle?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Quisiera saber el uso del operador `(+)` en la siguiente consulta y cuál es su posible equivalencia en MySQL.

```
SELECT 'E' tipo_envase, DECODE(NVL(pasi_parametro1,'-'),'-','CRE','CON') tipo_pago, vaca_serie, vaca_numero, vaca_loca_clave, vaca_clnt_numero, vaca_conv_numero, vaca_locl_clave,
         vaca_loco_clave, vaca_pedi_serie, vaca_pedi_numero, vaca_plbo_clave, vaca_toneladas, vaca_comentarios, pedi_tipa_clave, pedi_prod_clave, pedi_mone_clave, pedi_tipe_clave,
         pedi_plbo_stock
  FROM   scc_vales_carga, scc_pedidos, scc_productos, scc_parametros_sistema
  WHERE  vaca_status            = 'E'
  AND    vaca_tavi_numero       = pw_tarjeta
  AND    vaca_eqpr_fecha        = pw_fecha_tarjeta
  AND    pedi_serie             = vaca_pedi_serie
  AND    pedi_numero            = vaca_pedi_numero
  AND    prod_clave             = pedi_prod_clave
  AND    pasi_sist_clave    (+) = 'SCC'
  AND    pasi_planta_bodega (+) = '001'
  AND    pasi_parametro     (+) = 40
  AND    pasi_parametro1    (+) = pedi_tipa_clave
  AND    NOT EXISTS             (SELECT 'X'
                                 FROM   scc_parametros_sistema
                                 WHERE  pasi_sist_clave    = 'SCC'
                                 AND    pasi_planta_bodega = '001'
                                 AND    pasi_parametro     = 38
                                 AND    pasi_parametro1    = prod_prpr_clave)
  ORDER BY tipo_envase, tipo_pago, vaca_serie, vaca_numero;
```

Esto está en Oracle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es la sintaxis vieja para expresar un outer join.

Si te fijas, la clausula from lista todas las tablas, y las condiciones para unirlas están en el where.

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a, b
 where a.llave (+) = b.Llave
```

es equivalente a

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a 
       left outer join  b on a.Llave = b.Llave
```

Luego

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a, b
 where a.llave = (+) b.Llave
```

es equivalente a

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a 
       right outer join  b on a.Llave = b.Llave
```

Y finalmente

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a, b
 where a.llave (+) = (+) b.Llave
```

es equivalente a

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a 
       full outer join  b on a.Llave = b.Llave
```

Los queries que estás viendo fueron escritos en tiempos inmemoriales de Oracle.

[edit]
Para escribir la consulta mySQL equivalente, haría falta conocer la estructura de las tablas, pues los campos no están calificados en la consulta original, pero con lo dicho, esa parte queda como ejercicio para el OP.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la definición del uso de ese carácter. Si ya he encontrado la manera de pasar todo eso a mysql. Saludos

Comment: Excelente @Osiel, y bienvenido a StackOverflow. Si la información te ha sido de ayuda, considera [aceptar la respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Te invito también a realizar [el recorrido](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque la idea general de la respueta que dio @jachguate es correcta, casi todos los detalles especificos en su explicacion son incorrectos.

A continuacion expongo las correcciones para beneficio de los futuros lectores:

**Ejemplo #1**

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a, b
 where a.llave (+) = b.Llave
```

Segun @jachguate, es equivalente a:

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a 
       left outer join  b on a.Llave = b.Llave
```

... esto es incorrecto y al revez. Mas bien, es equivalente a:

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a 
 right outer join  b on a.Llave = b.Llave
```

... o tambien equivalente a:

```
select a.columnA, b.columnB
  from b
  left outer join a on a.Llave = b.Llave
```

**Ejemplo #2**

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a, b
 where a.llave = (+) b.Llave
```

Segun @jachguate, es equivalente a:

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a 
       right outer join  b on a.Llave = b.Llave
```

... nuevamente, esto es incorrecto. Primeramente, porque el query ni siquiera es valido, porque el símbolo `(+)` no esta en el lugar correcto. Probablemente quiso decir:

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a, b
 where a.llave = b.Llave (+)
```

... pero aun así, el equivalente no es correcto. Mas bien es:

```
select a.columnA, b.columnB
  from a
  left outer join b on a.Llave = b.Llave
```

... o tambien:

```
select a.columnA, b.columnB
  from b
 right outer join a on a.Llave = b.Llave
```

**Ejemplo #3**

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a, b
 where a.llave (+) = (+) b.Llave
```

segun @jachguate es equivalente a:

```
select a.columnaA, b.columnaB
  from a 
       full outer join  b on a.Llave = b.Llave
```

... tambien es incorrecto, por 2 razones:

1. Tal como en el ejemplo anterior, `(+) b.Llave` no es valido.  El símbolo `(+)` debe estar despues de la columna, no antes (ejemplo: `b.Llave (+)`.
2. No existe ninguna manera de expresar un `full outer join` usando el símbolo `(+)`. Tratar de hacerlo consigue el error: `a predicate may reference only one outer-joined table`.